# Windows 10 capping download speeds across all adapters

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10

For some reason, Windows 10 is limiting the download speed on all the network adapters on my PC to a small fraction of what it should be. I have a roughly 700 Mbps-down internet connection, but testing via Speedtest.net or any other speed testing service consistently results in only about 130 Mbps down. This isn't just evident in internet speed tests, either. Downloading files shows the same speed-capping behavior, whether I do it via Origin, Steam, a web browser, a network share in File Explorer, whatever.

Crucially, this isn't a problem limited to one driver or even a single network adapter. My motherboard happens to have two built-in Gigabit Ethernet ports (one an Intel I211, and the other an I219), and a Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4A 802.11AC wireless network adapter. No matter which I'm using the problem manifests the same: a seemingly hard cap on my download speed at right about 130 Mbps.

And before you start to think there's an easy solution, there's this too: I also have a Kubuntu installation running on this same PC. Under Kubuntu, using any of the network adapters I get the speeds I expect: e.g. Speedtest.net shows about 600-700 Mpbs on the download side, as it should. So I have to conclude that my hardware is fine, but something is desperately broken in Windows.

[Here's a pastebin of my system info](https://pastebin.com/raw/W1dAFLcS), if it's helpful.

Comment: Hook up your computer directly to the modem and check overall speed. It should match the ISP specification. Then try again via router. The router may be the limiting factor. If so, you would need to replace it with a faster router

Comment: Thanks @John, but note what I wrote about Kubuntu. Router can give me 600 Mbps just fine when I'm not under Windows.

Comment: Native, properly installed Windows does not slow down network speeds at all.

Comment: Is this a recent change, or you have only just noticed, or it has been like this for a long time?

Comment: Maybe a couple months at the most, definitely hasn't always been like this though.

Comment: When you compare it to a native Windows, do you mean that the slow Windows is running in a virtual machine in Kubuntu?

Comment: Windows Host most machine but I get the same results in a Virtual machines as well.

Comment: No, definitely not. I've got a native Windows installation that boots from one SSD, and a native Kubuntu installation that boots from another SSD. No VMs or anything of the sort going on here.

Comment: Here, it is not a Windows issue or a VM issue, so there must be something in your setup.

Comment: Agreed John. I was hoping it might be as simple as a bad driver, but then note what I said about the problem being the same across all adapters, wired *and* wireless. Plus the wireless card is Qualcomm and the Ethernet are both Intel, so it can't just be one bad driver.

Comment: @AdamJames Are you using Hyper-V and, if so, does your networking go via the Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Nope. I double checked and Hyper-V wasn't even enabled.

Comment: @AdamJames Maybe the antivirus software? I have had incidences of AVG slowing down internet access; reinstalling it made it work properly again.

Comment: @AndrewMorton My only anti-virus is the built-in Windows Defender. Tried disabling that, and the Windows firewall for good measure, but no effect. Good suggestion though.

Comment: @AdamJames There are plenty of suggestions in the Microsoft forum at [Slow Internet Speed on Windows 10 1809](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/slow-internet-speed-on-windows-10-1809/022c16ef-3c69-4472-b7e9-d0b7466916fc?auth=1). I assume you have a current backup ;)

Comment: Thanks Andrew! That at least got me on the path to finding the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be a complete and utter reset of all networking configuration, as documented [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheNuclearOptionResettingTheCrapOutOfYourNetworkAdaptersInVista.aspx).

In an administrator command prompt, run:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
nbtstat -R
nbtstat -RR
netsh int reset all 
netsh int ipv4 reset
netsh int ipv6 reset
netsh winsock reset
```

Note that arguments to `nbtstat` are case-sensitive and that the `int reset all` might not work on Windows 10.

Restart, and download speeds should be back to normal.