# The internet download speed drops to <20 Mbp/s randomly

Tags: windows-10, gigabit-ethernet

A few months ago I started noticing internet speed drops, to a point that the internet is almost unusable (sometimes around 10Mbps or 5Mbps, very rarely it drops to 120Mbps).

Running a speedtest confirms this. (expecting 250/25, so the upload is fine)[image: Speedtest during the issue]

Usually, the NetIO-GUI, which tests network speeds to a local networked machine, RX/TX speeds are close to 1Gbps, but during a download speed drop, the RX speeds are around 500Mbps. I tweaked some of my NIC's settings from within Intel's PROSet Adapter Config Utility, which also passes all the NIC problem check tests, when the issue is 'active'.

I recently switched Ethernet wall socket connection, both are in the same tube, which run down to the patch panel and into the UniFi Switch 24. All the cables are Cat-5E and the connection is forced to 1Gbps Full duplex, since there were some auto-negotiaton issues with UniFi switches.

I noticed that when the CPU is at a constant load, the NetIO-GUI speeds are all over the place, when I stop that constant load, the speeds are close to 1Gbps. The NetIO server is a VMWare ESXi VM that runs at 100% CPU load all the time and without any issues can download/upload 1Gbps. When I disable and enable the NIC in the Network adapter configuration screen, the issue is gone for an unkown amount of time.

All the Energy Saving things are disabled.

I'm running:

- Asus Prime X570 Pro motherboard (Intel I211 Gigabit network
  connection)
- AMD Ryzen 9 3900X
- 32GB of DDR4 RAM
- Windows 10 x64 Pro 2004 build 19041.546
- Asus GTX 780 DC2-OC2 (shouldn't matter, but for the sake of completeness)

Intel PROSet Adapter Information:

[image: Intel PROSet Information]

Intel uses strange version numbers for their driver packages, the Intel Network Connections version is 25.3.0.1, which strangely enough is not available on Intel's website anymore. The issue was also here on 25.1.1 and 25.2.

I tried the commands listed in the answer of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1521982/windows-10-capping-download-speeds-across-all-adapters/1522248#1522248) question.
CPU unloaded, still gets about 116Mbps/24.05Mbps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is a little bit unfortunate. It had nothing to do with my NIC or with the advanced settings.

The problem was most likely caused by an incorrect **D.O.C.P. profile** on my motherboard. I used the [DRAM Calculator](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/ryzen-dram-calculator/) tool by 1usmus to calculate the proper timings, I entered them in my BIOS (or UEFI however you want to call it) and I've been running at around (give or take 5Mbps) 250Mbps/25Mbps for two days straight.